# Преобразование числа в временной промежуток в формате 00:00:00

Tags: c#, время

На выходе из формулы у меня получается число float в часах. Нужно преобразовать его в временной формат 00:00:00:
Из него соответсвенно можно получить минуты и секунды. Как поступить дальше ?
К примеру:
s - секунды
m - минуты

```
если s > 60, то s-=60, m+=1
```

и соответсвенно для минут и часов. Так ?
Или можно как то иначе ?
немного пересмотрел вариант решения:

```
if (s>60) int k = s/60; s-=60*k; m+k;
```

**UPD1:**

```
TimeLabel.Text = TimeSpan.FromHours(dt).Seconds.ToString();
```

Не выводит ничего. Т.е = 0;

Comment: а чему равно `dt`? Может, у вас и правда 0 секунд? И ещё, почему вы выводите отдельно секунды? Почему не просто `TimeSpan.FromHours(dt).ToString()`?

Comment: если выводить просто TimeSpan.FromHours(dt).ToString() то выводит лишь часы. в минуты и секунды не преобразует...
вот формула со значениями:
dt = 80/(1000*(1+2))

Comment: @Sier: так проблема у вас с делением! Целочисленное деление даёт целый результат 0. Спорим, что в `dt` у вас 0? Попробуйте `80.0/(1000*(1+2))`. :-)

Comment: Дело в том что dt = x/(1000*(1+y)) где x и y - приводится к типу int. Чтобы привести их к типу float придется изрядно потрепать нервы переписывая код... ((

Comment: Так в dt у вас 0, из него вы никак не получите ненулевых секунд? хоть с `TimeSpan`, хоть без. Так что без правки кода не обойтись. Попробуйте, например, `dt = x/(1000.0*(1+y))`.

Comment: Вроде исправил, но, при выводе, если часов > 100 то выводится с десятичной точкой. как ее убрать ?

Comment: @Sier: это не десятичная точка, это количество дней. Попробуйте `ts.Days * 24 + ts.Hours`, если вам надо без дней.

Comment: @VladD, Понятно :) Но как привести все это в нормальный вид.. ? иначе у меня дни и млс отражаются ужастно....например: 13.15:40:47.9740000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если в часах `int`, то 0 минут и 0 секунд, верно? То есть никакие вычисления не нужны.

А вообще идеологически правильно так:

```
var t = TimeSpan.FromHours(hours)
```

и работать не с `int`, а со структурой `TimeSpan`.

---

Обновление:
у вас проблема с делением. `TimeSpan` работает правильно: вот [этот код](http://ideone.com/E3HE3r)

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var ts = TimeSpan.FromHours(80.0/(1000*(1+2)));
        Console.WriteLine(ts.Hours.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(ts.Minutes.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(ts.Seconds.ToString());
    }
}
```

выдаёт

> 0
> 1
> 36

---

Если надо вывести часы без дней, попробуйте `ts.Days * 24 + ts.Hours` или `(int)Math.Ceil(ts.TotalHours)`. К сожалению, `ts.ToString()` не умеет так, как вам хочется.

Comment: сорри ошибся... число выходит в формате float. TimeSpan пробовал, неудачно как то вышло.

Comment: Что значит "неудачно"? TimeSpan -- это канонический метод представления временных интервалов. Опишите. что именно с ним не вышло.

Comment: @Sier: обновил ответ

Comment: @VladD, спасибо. Проблема решена. :)

Comment: @Sier: пожалуйста!